# Give ListChangeListener initial state

Tags: java, collections, observers

I want to observe an ObservableList that is modified by completely seperate code. My problem is that I do not just want my ListChangeListener to be invoked when the list changes (when I attach my listener the list may already contain elements), but I also want the initial state to be passed to the listener.

Obviously I could do the following:

```
list.addListener(this::listenerMethod);
listenerMethod(fakeChange);
```

But with this approach any item that is added between the two method calls would be handled twice, which is not ideal.

When the order is reversed:

```
listenerMethod(fakeChange);
list.addListener(this::listenerMethod);
```

The second approach would totally ignore any elements added between the two method calls.

What would be the best way of dealing with such a situation?

Comment: It seems that what you should care about is knowing when your listener is invoked for the first time to process any pre-invocation elements

Comment: @efekctive Ok, so initially I though this was the solution. But your solution only works if  the list is changed at some point, which is not guaranteed. The list could remain in its initial state forever.

Comment: If it is not changed, the listener will never be invoked. A moot point

Comment: So probably you need something else other than a change listener

Comment: @efekctive The issue is that I have to use a ObservableList since I get the information in that form and I cannot replace the list with a custom implementation. In case it helps to clarify, the list in question is the one returned by the com.sun.javafx.stage.StageHelper#getStages() method.

Comment: you don't need to replace the observable list. what you need to change is when and how you verify its initial state. Since the change listener is you implementation, I would pass the list to the listener constructor and process the initial state at that point. If the listener is never invoked, you are covered. If this helps you, Let me know, I will post it as an answer

Comment: @efekctive Ok, I get what you mean. So in terms of code it would look something like `list.addListener(new CustomListChangeListener(list));`. This solves my problem, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you should care about is knowing when your listener is invoked for the first time to process any pre-invocation elements.

In your case since the listener may never be invoked what you need to change is when and how you verify the list initial state. Since the change listener is your implementation, I would pass the list to the listener constructor and process the initial state at that point. If the listener is never invoked, you are covered.